# ¿Qué significa el punto delante de algunas acepciones del DLE?

Tags: dle

Consultando, por ejemplo, [pera](https://dle.rae.es/?w=pera) en DLE se puede ver que recoge 8 acepciones, pero únicamente delante del 8 de de la 8ª acepción hay un punto negro y grueso:

> ● 8. adj. coloq. Dicho de una persona: Muy elegante y refinada, que raya en lo cursi.

¿Tiene algún significado especial esa marca?

Solo aparece cuando se accede al DLE con Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: Esto parece un _bug_ o una incidencia del trabajo :-D. Yo no puedo reproducirlo ni en Chrome ni en Firefox, pero sí con el Internet Explorer (Edge). Con IE puedo ver lo que indica Walen, un punto delante de la acepción octava y un cuadrado delante de pera ahogadiza. Entiendo por tanto que la respuesta es que **no significa nada** y es simplemente algún tipo de error con el documento que distintos navegadores interpretan de distinta manera (El Internet Explorar va siempre un poco a su bola...).

Comment: Y si te pones a ver el código con las herramientas de desarrollador de cualquiera de esos navegadores, ves que esa octava acepción tiene una _class_ de "j1", mientras que el resto de elementos de esa lista es de "j", Parecido con la entrada de "pera ahogadiza". Algunos de esos componentes tienen una clase distinta y el navegador los interpreta de distinta manera. Viendo que otros navegadores no lo interpretan de la misma manera no creo que sean elementos que estén pensados para ofrecer información adicional al usuario.

Comment: Y  el punto blanco  es *class* "j2"

Comment: @walen Pues incluye además el cuadrado blanco de "como pera, o peras, en tabaque" (y luego dile a Charlie que le pregunte a su colega Pérez Reverte que cómo les creamos una incidencia, Jira o lo que sea a los informáticos de la RAE...)

Comment: @walen Borré lo del navegador porque pensé que no era relevante

Answer (score 8):

En el sitio web de la RAE hay una guía sobre los signos empleados en su Diccionario.

En la versión PDF, [Abreviaturas y signos empleados](https://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Abreviaturas_y_signos_empleados.pdf), se indican al final de todo los siguientes:

[image]

Sin embargo, la [versión web de esa misma guía](https://dle.rae.es/contenido/abreviaturas-y-signos-empleados) no muestra tales símbolos, aunque sí las correspondientes descripciones:

[image]

La causa de esto puede ser o bien que los navegadores más recientes no muestren bien / no hagan caso de esos símbolos, o bien que la RAE haya decidido para sus versiones web sustituirlos por otros indicadores o directamente omitirlos.

Comment: ¡Qué bueno! Estas "bolas grandes" sí aparecen en todos los navegadores para el Diccionario de americanismos (ejemplo: http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=aOiRkzxBHx0A3cqsicm)

Comment: `¿tienen algún significado especial esas marcas? Sí, indican que esa definición es la primera de su categoría gramatical. Pero no aparecen en todos los navegadores, solo en los antiguos` Vamos, que es casi "legacy code".